# How to make Apyori generate rules larger than 2 items?

Tags: python, apriori

I have been trying to run apriori on a dataset and it has been working. However, I have not been able to make to generate rules larger than 2. I have seen multiple posts saying that I can change the min_length parameter to increase the minimum length of rules, but it does not seem to work for me and I don't even see a min_length parameter in the apyori file. There is an example of how to use apyori in Python in this github which also mentions the min_length parameter, but it is set to 2 and trying to change it in a notebook did not change anything for me.
https://github.com/AnaMakharadze/Recommendation-Systems

Answer (score 1):

According to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59612054/13184911), there is no `min_length` keyword in apriori algorithm, but the way of its implementation won't throw any errors.

Iterating over the items could be an alternative for what you are looking for:

```py
records = []
# items_col contains list of ids etc.
# example: [6500912, 6500695, 6500695, 6500695, 6500695]
for items in df['items_col']:
    uniq_items = list(set(products))
    if (len(uniq_items) > 1):
        records.append([str(j) for j in uniq_products])

rules = apriori(records, min_lift=lift_value, min_support=support_value)
```